# Use brew cask to build app before deploying it

Tags: macos, homebrew-cask

Is there a way for cask to build an app hosted on github before deploying it, instead of deploying a prebuilt app ?

Thanks.

Yann

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew-cask is intended to distribute prebuilt binaries.
What homebrew-cask does is just place files.

If you need to build the app from source, homebrew is the suitable place.

Comment: Hi, is there then a way to deploy the app just like cask would do after build ?

Comment: You can't install .app to `/Application` with formula, but installing apps to `libexec` and executing `brew linkapps your_formula` will install .app to `/Application`.

Comment: Great. Do you know if I can find an example somewhere ?

Comment: Actually, few packages do this. One example is qt5. See around line 130 in https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/805b2e0b0201b2560235eb3ee5c724d241ba42d5/Formula/qt5.rb